# Java Polymorphism code "Cannot find Constructor`

Tags: java, constructor

I'm trying to explain java Polymorphism to my self so I've simply created a project showing that `Family` is the `SuperClass` and `SubClasses are`BrothersSisters`

The thing is when I compile I receive an error saying that
`Cannot find the Constructor Sisters`
`Cannot find the Constructor Brothers`

Could someone explain to me?

Thanks guys.

```
class Family {

private String name,age;

public Family(String name,String age){

    this.name = name;
    this.age = age;

}

public String toString(){

    return "name : " + name + "\tage " + age ;
}
}

class Brothers extends Family{

public Brothers(String name, String age){
    super(name,age);
}
}
class Sisters extends Family{

public Sisters(String name, String age){
    super(name,age);
}

 }

class FamilyTest{

public static void main(String[] args){

Family[] Member= new Family[3];

Member[1] = new Sisters("LALA",22);
Member[2] = new Brothers("Mike",18);
 }
 }
```

Comment: When learning about inheritance and polymorphism is is very important to keep the terminology straight and intuitive. Here: Is `Brother` a kind of `Familiy`? No, it is a `FamilyMember`. Please use this "... is a kind of ..." test upfront and before declaring classes.

Answer (score 3):

You have `age` definded as String but you pass an integer to it.

```
Member[1] = new Sisters("LALA", "22");
Member[2] = new Brothers("Mike", "18");
```

should work but I would advice you to change `age` from String to int.

Answer (score 1):

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
Family[] Member= new Family[3];

Member[1] = new Sisters("LALA","22");
Member[2] = new Brothers("Mike","18");

}
```

Replace the main() with this code,

The error was : arguments for the constructors of `sisters` and `brothers` were String, but you passed `age` as an `Integer` .

Sugggestion : you may change the type of age to `int`, which is more correct.

Answer (score 0):

Please note that this is just one of the types of polymorphism you can use in Java, others are `Generics` and `Function overloading`